# About a function on Python

Tags: python, function

I'm a absolute beginner, and when I made a function to count the number of even ints on a given list, it didn't went as expected, and I can't see where I'm doing it wrong.

```
nums = [2,2,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def count_even(nums):
    for number in nums:
        num = 0
        if number % 2 == 0:
            num += number
            return num
        else:
            continue
```

The output is:

```
count_even(nums)
2
```

It stops on nums[1] for some obscure reason.
Or it just prints the first "2" and adds it, and I don't know how to fix it, yet.

Comment: The return statement exits your function and "returns" `num`.  So whenever a `return` is executed, the function is done. There is no more loop in your case. Also there are other problems with your function. For one, `num` is set to `0` with each loop. Another point is that you are _summing_ even numbers rather than counting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems here.

- You're setting `num = 0` every time through the loop, instead of just once at the start. So you're only going to get the very last count that you do.
- You're doing `num += number`, instead of `num += 1`, so instead of counting the even numbers, you're adding them.
- You're doing a `return num` as soon as the first even number is found, instead of only at the end of the function, after the loop. (And that also means that if there are no even numbers, instead of returning `0`, you return `None`).

While we're at it, you don't need `else: continue`, because continuing is already what happens by default when you fall off the end of a loop.

---

Anyway, this means it's not stopping at `nums[1]`, it's stopping at `nums[0]`—but it's adding `2` instead of `1` there, which makes things confusing. (It's always fun when bugs interact like that. Even more fun when they happen to exactly cancel out for your test case, like if you did `nums = [6,2,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and got back `6` and thought everything was working…)

---

So:

```
def count_even(nums):
    num = 0
    for number in nums:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            num += 1
    return num
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function stops on `nums[1]` because the `return` keyword exits the function and returns `num` (which is set to `0 + number`). If you want to print out the sum of all the even numbers in `nums` you could move the `return` statement to the end and take the `num = 0` expression out of the for loop (because it will reset to 0 after each iteration), like this:

```
def count_even(nums):
    num = 0
    for number in nums:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            num += number
        else:
            continue
    return num
```

Also, your else statement is redundant here, so you could simply remove it, leaving you with the following:

```
def count_even(nums):
    num = 0
    for number in nums:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            num += number
    return num
```

And you could simplify that further to:

```
def count_even(nums):
    evens = [number for number in nums if number % 2 == 0]
    return sum(evens)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def count_even(nums):
    return len([i for i in nums if i % 2 == 0])
```

Comment: Why build a list just to take its len? The usual idiom for this is `sum(1 for i in nums if i % 2 == 0)`. But at any rate, I doubt the OP is going to understand either.

Comment: @abarnert Great! Generator cost less memory. But I think *len* is more readable than *sum* in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code:

- Your `num` needs be defined outside the loop, so you can count every even number found. If you define it inside the loop, it resets to `0` every iteration.
- When you find an even number, you increment it towards the counter `num`. You need to instead increment `num` by 1.
- You `return` immediately when a even number is found, this means the function exits on the first even number. You instead want to return the total `num` at the end.
- You have an unnecessary `continue` in the `else` block. If a uneven number is found, simply ignore it.

Which these suggestions, you could implement your code like this:

```
nums = [2,2,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def count_even(nums):
    num = 0

    for number in nums:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            num += 1

    return num

print(count_even(nums))
# 6
```